# WP Query Bug? Cannot find out why posts are not found!

Tags: wp-query

Hello I have tried a lot now and I did not find a solution yet: When a page is loaded and I do a custom Query in the PHP code like this, it works and has a lot of results:

```
$q = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'video'));
```

When I am on a "custom taxonomy archive page" and have exactly the same code, the posts inside of the WP_Query object are always empty:

```
$q = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'video'));
```

I have compared the request strings:

On page (this is how it should be!):

```
string(243) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_ngn_posts.ID FROM wp_ngn_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_ngn_posts.post_type = 'video' AND (wp_ngn_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_ngn_posts.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY wp_ngn_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10"
```

On taxonomy archive page:

```
string(293) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_ngn_posts.ID FROM wp_ngn_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_ngn_posts.post_type = 'video' AND (wp_ngn_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_ngn_posts.post_status = 'private') AND wp_ngn_posts.post_content LIKE '%%'  ORDER BY wp_ngn_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10"
```

Why are new WP_Query objects built differntly on the different pages [where does this "LIKE '%%' come from"? Does anybody know why this happens and what I can do to fix this?

@Edit: The post type only supports title/custom field and yes - it has query_var set to true.

@Edit 2: May this problem be caused by the qTranslate Plugin?

@Edit 3: ... LIKE '%%' should not make a difference anyway although post content for this posts is always empty?

Comment: Does disabling qtranslate fix the issue?

Comment: Unfortunatly its not so easy to try this as it is a complex multisite installation and a lot of qTranslate functions are used inside of the content :-( Maybe an idea if it is possible to overwrite "wp_ngn_posts.post_content LIKE '%%'" or does anybody know where this may come from?